# I need help getting results from Core Data into an array in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I am doing a simple pull from Core Data, and filtering the results with a predicate, with the following:

```
do {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<CSTProjectDetails> = CSTProjectDetails.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "projectID == %@", cstProjectID)
    cstProjectDetails = try context.fetch(request)
} catch {
    print("There was an error fetching CST Project Details.")
}
```

When I try printing the following details, I get the following.

```
print("CSTProjectDetails: \(cstProjectDetails)")
```

This will produce something like this:

> CSTProjectDetails: [ (entity:
>   CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd000000000080004
>    ; data: ),  (entity:
>   CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd0000000000c0004
>    ; data: ),  (entity:
>   CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd000000000100004
>    ; data: ),  (entity:
>   CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd000000000140004
>    ; data: ),  (entity:
>   CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd000000000180004
>    ; data: )]

I tried casting "cstProjectDetails" as an array, and doing some tests with the results:

```
let hrData = self.cstProjectDetails as NSArray
print("There are \(hrData.count) items in this project")
```

This will actually print out the correct number of items that were pulled from Core Data.

If I do this:

```
dump(hrData)
```

I get something like this:

> - (entity: CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd000000000080004
>      ; data: ) #1
>
>   - super: LogsterBeta3.CSTProjectDetails
>
>     - super: NSManagedObject
>   - (entity: CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd0000000000c0004
>        ; data: ) #2
>   - super: LogsterBeta3.CSTProjectDetails
>
>     - super: NSManagedObject
>   - (entity: CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd000000000100004
>        ; data: ) #3
>   - super: LogsterBeta3.CSTProjectDetails
>
>     - super: NSManagedObject
>   - (entity: CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd000000000140004
>        ; data: ) #4
>   - super: LogsterBeta3.CSTProjectDetails
>
>     - super: NSManagedObject
>   - (entity: CSTProjectDetails; id: 0xd000000000180004
>        ; data: ) #5
>   - super: LogsterBeta3.CSTProjectDetails
>
>     - super: NSManagedObject

With all of that said, I attempted to access properties of the entity in a loop with something like this:

```
for logDetails in hrData {
    print (logDetails.species)
}
```

However, this produces an immediate error, saying "species" is not a valid member.

Can anybody let me know what I am missing here? How can I get the values from my NSFetchRequest into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get the values from my NSFetchRequest into an array?

You don't have to "get" anything "into an array". The result of calling `fetch` *is* an array. You had an array to start with.

Then you did a very odd thing: you cast `hrData` to an NSArray. Well, an NSArray has no element type. So now when you say

```
for logDetails in hrData {
```

Swift doesn't have any information about what a `logDetails` even *is*. It just types it as an AnyObject.

If you want to extract its `species` property you will need to cast your `logDetails` back down to whatever it really is, i.e. a CSTProjectDetails.

Alternatively, *don't* cast to an NSArray, since this erases your element type information. Cast down to a Swift array of CSTProjectDetails. Now Swift will have type information from the get-go.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand. How would I know what logDetails really is?  If I were to comment out everything below my do/try/catch function, what exactly would I need to do to grab the results?

Comment: n/m. I wrote my previous comment before I saw the updates that you made. That makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class TableViewVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var cstProject: CstProjectDetails?
var cstProjectDetails = [CstProjectDetails]()
let controller = CoredataController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        cstProjectDetails = controller.fetchCstProjectDetails()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cstProjectDetails.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CstProjectDetailsCell", for: indexPath) 

            self.cstProject = cstProjectDetails[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(cstProjectDetails: cstProject!)
            return cell
}
```

and

```
class CoredataController: NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    func fetchCstProjectDetails() -> [CstProjectDetails] {

        var cstProjectDetails = [CstProjectDetails]()
        let fetchProject: NSFetchRequest<CstProjectDetails> = CstProjectDetails.fetchRequest()

        do {
            let fetchedResult = try context.fetch(fetchCstProjectDetails)

            for project in fetchedResult as [NSManagedObject] {
                cstProjectDetails.append(project as! CstProjectDetails)
            }

        } catch {

            let error = error as NSError
            print("ATTEMPT FETCH ERROR IS: \(error)")
        }
        return cstProjectDetails
    }
}
```